TabControl with add button
So I'm building a Wpf Chromium Browser and right now I'm doing the Tabs. Everything works but the button to add a tab is handled as a own tab but it should only be a button. when i move it outside the tabcontrol, then the button is not positioned good and breaks everything.
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <TabItem HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource TabHeaderTemplate}">
        <local:TabContent />
    </TabItem>
    <Button Content="+" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Click="AddNewTab_Click" />

</TabControl>

DataTemplate.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeaderTemplate">
        <Grid Height="32" Width="200">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="New Document" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" />
            <Button Content="X" Grid.Column="2" Padding="0" Width="16" Height="16" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>



As explained above I want that the tabs add button is a button and not a tab

Take a look at this example:
    public class ContentData
    {
        public string? Text { get; set; }
        public string? Header { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ContentData> Content { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ContentData>();


        private static readonly string[] words = "As explained above I want that the tabs add button is a button and not a tab".Split();

        private RelayCommand? _addDataCommand;
        public RelayCommand AddDataCommand => _addDataCommand ??= new(() =>
        {
            ContentData data = new ContentData()
            {
                Text = words[Content.Count],
                Header = $"Tab #{Content.Count + 1}"
            };
            Content.Add(data);
            SelectedContent = data;
        });

        public ContentData SelectedContent { get => Get<ContentData>(); set => Set(value); }
    }

<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.ColinWalker.question79002772.AddTabWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.ColinWalker.question79002772"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AddTabWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DataViewModel x:Key="vm"/>

        <CompositeCollection x:Key="tabs.source">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Content, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <Button Content="+" Command="{Binding AddDataCommand, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>
        </CompositeCollection>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="template.header"
                      DataType="{x:Type local:ContentData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template.content"
                      DataType="{x:Type local:ContentData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource tabs.source}}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContent}"
                    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource template.header}"
                    ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource template.content}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


TabItem.Header made it! Thanks for your help.
code

<TabItem.Header>

</TabItem.Header>

code
